# How to navigate between page and open window using MVVM in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have read several article, tutorial, example. But I'm still unable to make navigation between page and windows happens.

```
> Visual Studio Community 2019 
> .NET Framework: 4.7.2
```

To make it simple, I have 3 pages and 1 window **ALL VIEW IS FULL SCREEN FOR KIOSK APPLICATION**. Details page as below:

```
MVVMApps.sln
│
├── PageInitialize.xaml
├── PageHome.xaml
└──── PageSelectLanguage.xaml
               └── WinMessage.xaml
```

I have try MvvmLight by GalaSoft but stuck on navigate from `PageInitialize.xaml` to `PageHome.xaml`. And I just found article from [GalaSoft](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/nav1.cshtml) that WPF is coming soon for `INavigationService`. Most tutorial I found is sampling for Xamarin.

Plus I got undefined assembly `using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;` which I see it's available on Enterprise. On Nuget, installing MvvmLight will install CommonServiceLocator too.

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private static bool initialized;
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        //Fix to keep blend happy
        if (initialized) { return; }
        initialized = true;

        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<PageInitializeViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<PageHomeViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<PageSelectLanguageViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<WinMessageViewModel>();
        SetupNavigation();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    public PageInitializeViewModel PageInitializeViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<PageInitializeViewModel>();
    public PageHomeViewModel PageHomeViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<PageHomeViewModel>();
    public WinMessageViewModel WinMessageViewModel=> ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<WinMessageViewModel>();
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }
    private void SetupNavigation()
    {
        var navigationService = new Helpers.NavigationService<Helpers.NavigationPage>();
        navigationService.ConfigurePages();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<Helpers.INavigationService<Helpers.NavigationPage>>(() => navigationService);
    }
}
```

I have go through some of tutorial without MvvmLight:-

1. [Navigating between views in WPF / MVVM](https://www.technical-recipes.com/2018/navigating-between-views-in-wpf-mvvm/)
2. [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)
3. [MVVMTest](https://github.com/ipinlnd/MVVMTest)

Each article use different approach and since I'm not familiar with it, once error line appear and no Intellisense suggestion, I cannot continue to find the solutions.

Is it hard to use MVVM in WPF if I have multiple Page and Window screen? Currently, I have a complete WPF App but it use code-behind. I want to move to MVVM since I've read that MVVM is better than code-behind somewhere. MVVM for single page is not a problem as I have done before and it is totally awesome when using MVVM.

Should I retain to use code-behind in WPF if navigation is almost impossible to have workable answer?

Comment: If it's a small application, it doesn't matter if you use code behind. The idea behind MVVM is that you separate Business logic from your view, so you swap out our views, for example you may want to move your WPF application into a web application, With MVVM, ideally you only have to rewrite the views.
Is Navagtion impossible in WPF ? no, Prism (https://prismlibrary.com/) has a good implementation of navigation. I'm sure there a million ways you could do navigation in WPF

Comment: @AthulRaj yes it is a small application targetting retail customer like servicing (fast food). I want to move to MVVM because the basic is I want to experience and know more about MVVM. So, it is a better start. Navigation in WPF is simple. But navigation in MVVM is totally hard to find. I'll explore Prism and study about it a bit see what can I get from it

Answer (score 2):

Start simple and set navigationservice, viewmodellocators and everything but the basics to one side for now.

I would avoid all those ....locator classes anyhow. They necessarily rely on an anti pattern IMO.

Just use viewmodel first and a single window app.

The basic pattern involves a MainWindow, the Datacontext of which is MainWindowViewModel.
You might want a menu or some such but the part you will switch out is the content of a contentcontrol.

Bind the Content property of your ContentControl to a public object property on mainwindowviewmodel. Call that CurrentViewModel for the sake of discussion.

Define a viewmodel and usercontrol per view you will switch between. Thus HomeView and HomeViewModel, LoginView and LoginViewModel. And so on.

In a resource dictionary, create a datatemplate for each view associating your usercontrol with the type of it's viewmodel.

Merge this resource dictionary in app.xaml.

To navigate.

Instantiate a new viewmodel of the sort you need.

Set CurrentViewModel  to that instance.

It will then be templated into UI.

There are numerous variations of this - it's called viewmodel first and you should be able to easily google a few examples.

Here's one I wrote for a slightly different purpose:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52485.wpf-tips-and-tricks-using-contentcontrol-instead-of-frame-and-page-for-navigation.aspx

You can use a similar approach with pages if you really want pages:

A simplified view:

```
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page1ViewModel}">
            <local:Page1/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Page2ViewModel}">
            <local:Page2/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="ViewSelect"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ViewChoices}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewChoice, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Frame Grid.Column="1"
               Content="{Binding SelectedViewChoice.VM}"
               NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
               />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The very much simplified viewmodel.

```
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ViewChoice> ViewChoices { get; set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ViewChoice>
        {
            new ViewChoice{ Name="Page One", VM=new Page1ViewModel()},
             new ViewChoice{ Name="Page Two", VM=new Page2ViewModel()},
        };

        private ViewChoice selectedViewChoice;

        public ViewChoice SelectedViewChoice
        {
            get { return selectedViewChoice; }
            set { selectedViewChoice = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

ps

If you decide to learn prism I would start with delegatecommand and stop there until you have written at least one wpf app.
There's a HUGE slew of functionality in PRISM and most apps don't actually benefit from regions and dynamic composition.

If you prefer mvvmlight ( I do ) then for core you're best getting the source code and using that. You want commandWPF namespace and this has a reliance on net old in the nuget package. The version that does not will not support command canexecute requery well.

I hope that's sufficient info without being overwhelming. Tricky to both be clear and not drown someone with info.

Comment: I've read some answer as for MVVM, it hierarchy as MvvmLight, Prism and MEF. I'm currently try to use the one that you mention. One thing is, on my current architecture, each view have their own timer which will initialized after `InitializedComponent()`. At timer hit when no response, then screen will automatically back to home. But on each viewmodel class, it will initialized at first as I add viewmodel class to moderator on `MainWindowViewModel.ViewChoices`. I'm thinking about timer, hardware initialize(cash acceptor, card terminal, printer) on each viewmodel. Is there any way?

Comment: Sure. You can pass a reference to mainwindowviewmodel in and call a method or use mvvmlight messenger or some any mediator. You can add dependency injection in. Build a base viewmodel with return to home functionality in it... all sorts.

Comment: Before you adopt complicated stuff. Think about whether you need it. Do you need MEF? Will the client really benefit from the complexity that dynamically discovering dll adds? Maybe you will deliver different stuff to different clients. If you don't though, it's just overhead in your development. Simple first. Complicate things when you find you need to.

Comment: Of course simple is better. I might not need something complex unless there is not other options. Previously, I'm using MvvmLight. But I got stuck on how to do navigation to other page. I already setup `ViewModelLocator` but I'm don't know how to call it. Since I've never done a MVVM with navigation before. Just MVVM without navigation had only done just because I want to know what is MVVM actually.

Comment: You don't need viewmodellocator. At all. Or at least you're unlikely to need it. I work with mvvmlight routinely and use viewmodel first navigation.

Comment: Does MVVM in WPF is develop for application that have button on side like normal accounting software, or it can be use for something like Food Ordering Kiosk or Mall Information Kiosk or Council Payment Kiosk where app is full screen and each page having different button and function? I ask because I have create sampling from your article and it look like side menu with view. As my navigation will be depend on which button on each usercontrol. If click back, it will go to previous screen. If next, go next screen. If select, open product detail screen.

Comment: You can work either way. Or a mix. A set menu, a set menu with additions the current view injects or each view has it's own menu. Just depends what you're doing. Pages become more useful if the user is going back to a previous page. In which case the way they maintain view state is a plus rather than just a negative.